# "To Do"/bugs database integrating with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

### Environment

```
Language: Java
IDE: Eclipse
Source control: SVN
```

### Objective

Track/manage bugs/TODOs from within Eclipse

### Current solution

Using Eclipse Java "task tags":

```
/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.coreorg.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.taskTags=TODO,MUST,SHOULD,COULD,...
```

and simply leveraging the automatic task creation of the IDE linked to the task tags.

### Desired solution

Something that works with an external database and that could return reports, integrating directly into Eclipse for the coding part and being free for the "server" part

Can anybody help me, please?

Comment: Would you be willing to use something like bugzilla?

Comment: That's the only one I actually found myself through extensive Googling... haven't installed it yet; how's the integration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run your own [Bugzilla](http://www.bugzilla.org/) server or utilize a hosted issue tracker service. There are a number of such services, many offering free accounts for projects with low number of users.

For Eclipse integration, you will want to use [Mylyn](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/). It has a number of connectors for open source and commercial issue tracking servers. You can query the issue tracker as well as create and modify tasks right from Eclipse.